# Aiogram. помогите с callback dp.callback_query_handler

Tags: python, aiogram, callback, inline

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

нужно что бы при нажатии на одну из этих кнопок, запускалась соответствующая функция.

код, который не работает (ничего не происходит. даже если туда запихнуть print()):

```
@dp.callback_query_handler(text="speakers")
async def audiodevice(message: types.Message):
    change_to_speakers()
```

код кнопок:

```
button_volume_headset = InlineKeyboardButton(text ="", callback_data = 'headset')
button_volume_speakers = InlineKeyboardButton(text="", callback_data = 'speakers')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В вашем коде Вы указали `text` вместо `callback_data`, поэтому ваше обработчик не срабатывает.

Отредактируйте этот фрагмент таким образом:

```python
@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda c: c.data == 'speakers')
async def audiodevice(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery):
    await callback_query.answer()  # Отправляем подтверждение обработки callback запроса
    await change_to_speakers()  # Вызываем вашу функцию
```

Comment: спасибо огромное ♥

Comment: На здоровье, успехов в Ваших проектах :)